# foreach very slow with large number of values

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel, mclapply

I'm trying to use `foreach` to do parallel computations. It works fine if there are a small number of values to iterate over, but at some point it becomes incredibly slow. Here's a simple example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(8)

out1 <- foreach(idx=1:1e6) %do%
    {
        1+1
    }

out2 <- foreach(idx=1:1e6) %dopar%
    {
        1+1
    }

out3 <- mclapply(1:1e6,
                 function(x) 1+1,
                 mc.cores=20)
```

`out1` and `out2` take an incredibly long time to run. Neither of them even spawns multiple threads for as long as I keep them running. `out3` spawns the threads almost immediately and runs very quickly. Is `foreach` doing some sort of initial processing that doesn't scale well? If so, is there is a simple fix? I really prefer the syntax of `foreach`.

I should also note that the actual code that I'm trying to parallelize is substantially more complicated than 1+1. I only show this as an example because even with this simple code foreach seems to be doing some pre-processing that is incredibly slow.

Comment: I can't answer how to use foreach for this, but I can suggest using the `future.apply` package.

You set it up using `library(future.apply); plan(multiprocess(workers = 3))`, and then you can execute your function with:
`future_sapply(X = 1:1e6, FUN = function(x) {1 + 1})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the forach/doParallel vignette says (to a code much smaller than yours):

> Note well that this is not a practical use of doParallel. This is our
>   “Hello, world” program for parallel computing. It tests that
>   everything is installed and set up properly, but don’t expect it to
>   run faster than a sequential for loop, because it won’t! sqrt executes
>   far too quickly to be worth executing in parallel, even with a large
>   number of iterations. With small tasks, the overhead of scheduling the
>   task and returning the result can be greater than the time to execute
>   the task itself, resulting in poor performance. In addition, this
>   example doesn’t make use of the vector capabilities of sqrt, which it
>   must to get decent performance. This is just a test and a pedagogical
>   example, not a benchmark.

So it might be in the nature of your setting that it is not faster.

Instead try without parallelization but using vectorization:

```
q <- sapply(1:1e6, function(x) 1 + 1 )
```

It does exactly the same like your example loops and is done in a second.
And now try this (it does still exactly the same thing exaclty the same times:

```
x <- rep(1, n=1e6)
r <- x + 1
```

It adds to 1e6 `1`s a `1` instantly. (The power of vectorization ...)

The combination of `foreach` with `doParallel` is from my personal experience much slower than if you use the bioinformatics `BiocParallel` package from the repository Bioconda. (I am a bioinformatician and in bioinformatics, we have very often calculation-heavy stuff, since we have single data files of several gigabytes to process - and many of them).
I tried your function using `BiocParallel` and it uses all assigned CPUs by 100% (tested by running `htop` during job execution) the entire thing took 17 seconds.

For sure - with your lightweight example, this applies:

> the overhead of scheduling the task and returning the result 
>   can be greater than the time to execute the task itself

Anyway, it seems to use the CPUs more thoroughly than `doParallel`. So use this, if you have calculation-heavy tasks to be get done.
Here the code how I did it:

```
# For bioconductor packages, the best is to install this:
install.packages("BiocManager")

# Then activate the installer
require(BiocManager)

# Now, with the `install()` function in this package, you can install
# conveniently Bioconductor packages like `BiocParallel`
install("BiocParallel")

# then, activate it
require(BiocParallel)

# initiate cores:
bpparam <- bpparam <- SnowParam(workers=4, type="SOCK") # 4 or take more CPUs

# prepare the function you want to parallelize
FUN <- function(x) { 1 + 1 }

# and now you can call the function using `bplapply()`
# the loop parallelizing function in BiocParallel.
s <- bplapply(1:1e6, FUN, BPPARAM=bpparam) # each value of 1:1e6 is given to 
# FUN, note you have to pass the SOCK cluster (bpparam) for the 
# parallelization
```

For more info, go to [the vignette of the BiocParallel package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/BiocParallel/inst/doc/Introduction_To_BiocParallel.pdf).
Look at bioconductor how many packages it provides and all well documented.
I hope this helps you for your future parallel computing stuff.

Comment: Thanks for some of the suggestions. The actual code that I'm running in parallel is a large-scale estimation and definitely can't be vectorized. My example was strictly to illustrate that foreach seems to be doing some pre-processing that is incredibly slow for a large index. It doesn't even begin doing the parallel work for quite a while. I can try that package as well.

Comment: @Rob Richmond: Yes, I know, you want to use it for real processes which will need to use more of the ressources. Just I was explaining why your special example disappoints you. And yes, I think that with `BiocParallel` you might be more content.

Comment: I've been playing with `BiocParallel` and have found it to be a fantastic alternative to `foreach`. It seems like there is something about `foreach` that is causing it to hang on large numbers of tasks which remains unanswered. That said, I'm going to accept your answer since it improves my overall workflow. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I am delighted that I could help! And yes, I once beginning of this year tried also around with doParallel and foreach - and I was disappointed with both as well ... Thanks!